# Some EKEvents doesn't match predicate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ekeventkit

I'm working on a calendar app.

For a month I loop on all my day to get events of this day. I have to do this to handle recurent events and events longer than one day.

It work great except for one case: the last day of a several day long event. I see the event for the other days of this event but not for the last one. (I'm in GMT+1 Time Zone, that's why I have this hours)

```
SEARCH FOR THE LAST DAY OF EVENT
Start:  2013-03-25 23:00:00 +0000
End:    2013-03-26 22:59:59 +0000

EVENT
Start:  2013-03-24 21:00:06 +0000
End:    2013-03-26 21:00:06 +0000

No results!
```

Here is the method returning events for the day:

```
+ (NSArray *)ekEventsWithStartDate:(NSDate*)startDate endDate:(NSDate*)endDate
{
    NSLog(@"ekEventsWithStartDate:%@ endDate:%@",startDate,endDate);
    NSPredicate *predicate = [_eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate
                                                                  endDate:endDate
                                                                calendars:nil];

    NSArray *events = [_eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"events (%d):%@",[events count],events);
    return events;
}
```

Here is the event details:

```
EKEvent <0xb0635e0> {EKEvent <0xb0635e0> 
{title =  24-26 Mars 10 PM; 
 location = ; 
 calendar = EKCalendar <0xb3c3c80> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #0E61B9;}; 
 alarms = (null);  
 URL = (null); 
 lastModified = 2013-03-19 22:11:10 +0000; 
 timeZone = Europe/Paris (GMT+01:00) offset 3600}; 
 location = ; 
 startDate = 2013-03-24 21:00:06 +0000; 
 endDate = 2013-03-26 21:00:06 +0000; 
 allDay = 0; 
 floating = 0; 
 recurrence = (null); 
 attendees = (null)}
```

Here is the log for the 3 days of this event from ekEventsWithStartDate method:

```
ekEventsWithStartDate:2013-03-23 23:00:00 +0000 endDate:2013-03-24 22:59:59 +0000
events (1):(
    "EKEvent <0x9b44c00> {EKEvent <0x9b44c00> {title =  24-26 Mars 10 PM; location = ; calendar = EKCalendar <0xb336870> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #0E61B9;}; alarms = (null); URL = (null); lastModified = 2013-03-19 22:11:10 +0000; timeZone = Europe/Paris (GMT+01:00) offset 3600}; location = ; startDate = 2013-03-24 21:00:06 +0000; endDate = 2013-03-26 21:00:06 +0000; allDay = 0; floating = 0; recurrence = (null); attendees = (null)}"
)

ekEventsWithStartDate:2013-03-24 23:00:00 +0000 endDate:2013-03-25 22:59:59 +0000
events (1):(
    "EKEvent <0xb28b970> {EKEvent <0xb28b970> {title =  24-26 Mars 10 PM; location = ; calendar = EKCalendar <0xb336870> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #0E61B9;}; alarms = (null); URL = (null); lastModified = 2013-03-19 22:11:10 +0000; timeZone = Europe/Paris (GMT+01:00) offset 3600}; location = ; startDate = 2013-03-24 21:00:06 +0000; endDate = 2013-03-26 21:00:06 +0000; allDay = 0; floating = 0; recurrence = (null); attendees = (null)}"
)

ekEventsWithStartDate:2013-03-25 23:00:00 +0000 endDate:2013-03-26 22:59:59 +0000
events (0):(null)
```

Why the method return null array?

Subsidiary question: is there a better way to get events for each days of a month? I'm looking for better performances.

Thank you for your help!

**Edit 20/03/2013:**
I figure out thanks to Dhruvik that my code works perfectly for iOS 5.X but doesn't work for iOS 6.X (no test for 4.X).

I check events and dates for 5.X and 6.X version and the only difference I saw is in event calendar timezone property:

```
iOS 5.X
timeZone = Europe/Paris (CET)

iOS 6.X
timeZone = Europe/Paris (UTC+01:00)
```

This problem doesn't concern full day events.

**Do you have same problem with iOS 6.X?**

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code to fecth Event, which i've implemented in my app..

in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) EKEventStore *eventStore;
@property (nonatomic, retain) EKCalendar *defaultCalendar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *eventsList;
```

in .m

```
//This code will fecth the events from one day Before the current date..

- (void) fetchevents
{

   eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

   eventsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

   [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
       // handle access here
   }];

   // Get the appropriate calendar
   NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

   // Create the start date components
   NSDateComponents *oneDayAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
   oneDayAgoComponents.day = -1; // From which date you have to fetch Events from calander, as per your need subtract the days from current date

   NSDate *oneDayAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDayAgoComponents
                                              toDate:[NSDate date]
                                             options:0];

   NSLog(@"%@", oneDayAgo);

   // Create the end date components
   NSDateComponents *oneYearFromNowComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
   oneYearFromNowComponents.year = 0;
   NSDate *oneYearFromNow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneYearFromNowComponents
                                                   toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                  options:0];
   NSLog(@"%@", oneYearFromNow);

   //Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
   NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:oneDayAgo endDate:oneYearFromNow                                                                                      calendars:nil];


   NSArray *events_Array = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate: predicate];

   for (EKEvent *eventToCheck in events_Array)
   {
       [eventsList addObject:eventToCheck.title ];
   }
}
```

Hope it helps., Happy coding.. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your code. I create a new empty project to test with it (it's very close to my code) and I have the same problem. But thanks to your answer I test in several iOS and I discovered that my problem doesn't appear for iOS 5.X, it's just for 6.X (I doesn't test 4.X). I'm wondering if this is an Apple regression.

Comment: okk.. and ya it may b regression from Apple. so have u got complete solution from my code?

Comment: No, I have the same code as you and it doesn't work for iOS 6.X

Comment: Ok, you have to test with an event of 3 days (not in full day mode) and try to get the event with start date at the begining of the #3 day (00:00) and end date at the end of the #3 day (23:59)

Comment: @Dhruvik can you help me if we can get trigger when any particular event get fire ?